# Coordinate system of orientable manifolds must be on connected domain?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am studying spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* by myself,now a sophomore college student majoring in Mathematics. In [Spivak - Calculus on Manifolds, Comments and Errata](https://www.jirka.org/spivak-errata.html),the author said "Page 118) In definition of orientation the W must be connected, otherwise no manifold would be orientable." Why is it necessary to require the open subset  W in $\mathbf{R^n}$ must be connected ? I need some details to explain if the condition of "connected" were canceled,no manifold would be orientable.

> (page 118)
>
> It is often necessary to choose an orientation $\mu_x$ for each tangent space $M_x$ of a manifold $M$. Such choices are called **consistent** provided that for every coordinate system $f : W \to \mathbf R^n$ and $a, b \in W$ the relation
>   $$ 
>  [f_{\ast}((e_1)_a), \ldots, f_{\ast}((e_k))_a] = \mu_{f(a)}
> $$
>   holds if and only if
>   $$
>  [f_{\ast}((e_1)_b), \ldots, f_{\ast}((e_k)_b)] = \mu_{f(b)}.$$
>   Suppose orirentations $\mu_{x}$ have been chosen consistently.If  $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$  is  a coordinate system such that $$
>  [f_{\ast}((e_1)_a), \ldots, f_{\ast}((e_k))_a] = \mu_{f(a)}
> $$ for one, and hence for  every $a\in W,$ then $f$ is called **orientation-preserving.**  If $f$ is not orientation-preserving and $T :\mathbb R^k  \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation with $\det T=-1,$ then $f\circ T$ is orientation-preserving. Therefore there is an orientation-preserving coordinate system around each point.

For the notation. With $v_p$ he denotes the tangent vector $v$ at the point $p$, for a function $f : A \to \mathbf R^m$ with $A \subseteq \mathbf R^n$ differentiable on $A$ we have $f_{\ast}(v_p) := (Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}$ and for a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ he denotes by $[v_1, \ldots, v_n]$ the orientation of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Also a coordinate system is defined as:

> (page 111)
>
> $\textbf{5-2 Theorem}$
>
> A subset $M$ of $\mathbf R^n$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold if and only if for each point $x \in M$ the following ''coordinate condition'' is satisfied:
>
> (C) There is an open set $U$ containting $x$, an open set $W \subseteq \mathbf R^k$, and a $1-1$ differentiable function $f : W \to \mathbf R^n$ such that
>
> (1) $f(W) = M \cap U$,
>
> (2) $f'(y)$ has rank $k$ for each $y \in W$,
>
> (3) $f^{-1} : f(W) \to W$ is continuous.
>
> Such a function $f$ is called a **coordinate system** around $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly little example: on the manifold $\mathbb{R}$, consider the following coordinate system:
$$W=(0,1)\cup (2,3)$$
$$U=(0,1)\cup (2,3)$$
$$f(y)=\begin{cases}1-y&0<y<1\\y&2<y<3\end{cases}$$
If we try to match this with the usual coordinates on $\mathbb{R}$, the orientation would be inconsistent; it flips between the two halves of $W$ using $f$, while it doesn't flip in the usual coordinates.

And that's the problem; every manifold has examples like this, where we can take two disconnected pieces out of a larger coordinate system and flip one of them around for an opposite orientation. If we allowed disconnected pieces, every orientation would be inconsistent in this way.